# Understanding Stroke and StrokeThickness in relation to Height

Tags: wpf

Below I have a rectangle:

```xml
<Rectangle ClipToBounds="False" Grid.Row="1"
           StrokeThickness="6"
           StrokeDashArray=".5"
           Height="2"
           Stroke="Green" />
```

In the definition above, I have observed that to see the effect of `StrokeDashArray=".5"`, I have to maintain the `StrokeThickness` between `6 to 9`. If I give anything `below 6` or `above 9`, I see a straight line.

I have two questions here:

1. In the above example, `StrokeDashArray` effect does not work `below 6` and `above 9`. Why?
2. I think there is a relation between height and `StrokeThickness`. Can someone please explain?

When I read the MSDN Definition on stroke thickness it says:

> Gets or sets the width of the Shape outline

I do not understand this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are actually four stroked lines that surround the Rectangle, and that those lines are drawn inside the Rectangle bounds. Having a StrokeThickness that is significanty larger than one dimension of the Rectangle (e.g. its Height) results in two lines that are drawn on top of each other. When these lines are dashed, one can easily imagine that the dashes of the one line cover the gaps in the other, and the visual result looks like a non-dashed line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stroke dash array is not expressed in pixels, it's dependent upon stroke thickness to get the final pixel value for each number in the array.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801980/evenly-spaced-dashes-with-strokedasharray) if you want to understand all the details behind it.

Generally speaking: The `StrokeThickness` tells WPF how thick
the line should be in pixels.

`StrokeDashArray` is a property that allows us to define the dashes and gaps in a
line. The values in the array alternate between the length of the dash and the
length of the gap. The values are also relative to the thickness of the stroke, so a
value of 1.0 means that the length of the corresponding dash or gap is equal to the
width of the stroke.

In your code you tell WPF to draw a dash that is 0.5 times of the width of the stroke but you didn't give the length of the gap, for example:

```
StrokeDashArray=".5 1"
```

This example says that the gap is equal to 1 time of the width.
Buttom line you need to define the gap for getting the wanted gap between the dashes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly what I wanted